# What exactly is Excitonium matter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, astronomy, matter

After 50 years of theories and thwarted attempts, scientists have finally proved the existence of a new form of matter. The never-before-detected condensate is called excitonium, a name first coined in the 1960s by Harvard theoretical physicist Bert Halperin. Halperin is now 76.

> “It’s as close to ‘proved’ as you’re ever going to get in science,”

Abbamonte, a physics professor at the University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign, told [Newsweek.](https://www.yahoo.com/news/physics-breakthrough-form-matter-excitonium-183206794.html)

What is this newly discovered matter? How does it differ from other forms of matter? Will it have any impact on current physic theories?

Comment: The Newsweek article provided a link to this Science article: http://science.sciencemag.org/content/358/6368/1314

Comment: There's this amazing thing called "Google".  Maybe you've heard of it?